# JBehave story if condition

Tags: automated-tests, jbehave

I want to execute a step only if it mets certain condition.
For instance,

Given a lists of days and MonthYear

If list contains a 30 days month then

When the user enters 31 for 30 days month
Then the error message shown is 'Invalid date'

Is it possible to write If condition in the JBehave story?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a IF in a Given/When/Then pattern.
In your example, the "if list contains a 30 days months" can be seen as "if the user choose a month with 30 days".

So, your example could probably be written like that:

```
Given a lists of days and MonthYear
When the user enters 31 in days AND user choose a month with 30 days 
Then the error message shown is 'Invalid date'
```

Comment: I guess "...AND user choose a month with 30 days" is a step. What if there is no 30-days month present in the list? The way it is used means it is going to excecute (tries to to chose 30-days month from the list) irrespective of 30-days month present or not.